# Select elements of a list which are functions of specified set of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following list:

```
mylist = {1, 2, x, 2y^2, (1 + x)/(y + 2), 1 + z}
```

And I want to output the elements in this list which are a function of x or y, which in this case would be

```
desiredoutput = {x, 2y^2, (1 + x)/(y + 2)}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Select[mylist, Not@*FreeQ[x | y]]
```

Comment: I liked Syed's use of ContainsAny and Variables--more semantically clear. Keeping the point-free style, you could try `Select[mylist, ContainsAny[{x, y}]@*Variables]`

Comment: (+1) In both cases. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = {1, 2, x, 2 y^2, (1 + x)/(y + 2), 1 + z};
```

---

Using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, ContainsAny[Variables[#], {x, y}] & /@ #] &@mylist
```

> `{x, 2 y^2, (1 + x)/(2 + y)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, x, 2 y^2, (1 + x)/(y + 2), 1 + z};
```

via `Position`

```
p = Union @ Position[list, x | y][[All, 1]]
```

> {3, 4, 5}

Using `Query`

```
Query[p] @ list
```

> {x, 2*y^2, (1 + x)/(2 + y)}

Using `Extract`

```
Extract[List /@ p] @ list
```

> {x, 2*y^2, (1 + x)/(2 + y)}